# Analytic onto maps from D to D

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

We just characterized using the Schwarz Lemma the conformal self maps of the open unit disk.  I am now trying to characterize the holomorphic onto maps from $\mathbb{D}$ onto $\mathbb{D}$.  As a natural starting point, I tried constructing various surjective maps that failed to be one-to-one, but am having trouble finding any!  Can someone give me a push in the right direction?

Comment: $z^2,\, z^3,\, z^4,\,z^5,\,z^6,\,\dotsc$ These all have $f(0) = 0$. Generally, any product of finitely many such maps may be such a map.

Answer (score 0):

Such functions ($\,\,f:D\to D$ holomorphic and onto, but not 1-1) are:

1. $f_n(z)=\lambda z^n$, $\lvert \lambda\rvert=1$.
2. $g_{n,a}(z)=\lambda\left(\dfrac{z-a}{1-\overline{a}z}\right)^{\!n},\,$ $\lvert a\rvert<1,\,$ $\lvert \lambda\rvert=1$.

Comment: Can I have a small hint in proving that these are the only such maps?